# Problemas com IReports

Tags: ireport, jasper-reports

Ultimamente estou criando alguns relatórios para minha aplicação utilizando o Jasper Reports (IReports) só que venho me deparando com alguns problemas.

Hoje estou utilizando o plugin para Netbeans porém de um momento para outro ele acusa um erro e não me permite gravar as alterações realizadas, outra hora não realiza preview procurei saber e descobri que uma certa versão havia um bug, mas gostaria se somente eu estou passando por estes problemas, ou existe uma solução ou correção para este caso.

Eu já tentei usar os plugins da Versão 5.6.0 e da versão 3.7.5 mas com nenhum consegui sucesso.

Comment: Qual versão você está usando champs?

Comment: A versão do plugin é 5.6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara eu também estou utilizando este plugin, no meu caso o ambiente é `Linux (Ubuntu 15.04)`, o plugin `iReport 5.5.0` e o `NetBeans 8.0.2`, eu considero este plugin bem estável apesar de esporadicamente acontecerem problemas parecidos com os reportados por você.

No meu caso algumas vezes quando vou fazer o preview o mesmo também não funciona, nesses casos sempre existe um erro no relatório que impede sua renderização, por isso o preview não funciona, eu consigo encontrar o erro mais facilmente executando um teste unitário que gere o relatório.

Para mim o único erro que incomodo é que as vezes quando vou alterar diretamente o XML do relatório ele trava a edição do XML, ai tenho que fechar o relatório e abrir novamente.

No mais considero um bom plugin, utilizo diariamente e resolve meus problemas.

Espero ter colaborado, até mais.